# Remove punctuation and replace whitespace

Tags: regex

The following is a sample string I will be searching which will be on a separate line with other strings:

> Chapter 1: My name is: Shojib (aka mhs)

Here is my regular expression to find that particular line: `(Chapter)( )([0-9])(:)( .*)`

Now I want to keep the words and integers, and remove the punctuation, and separate each words and integers with an underscore. For example, this is how the format should look after replacing:

> Chapter_1_My_name_is_Shojib_aka_mhs

Comment: What language are you using?  I'd almost say using a find and replace for non alphabet chars to '_' would be pretty simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you didn't mention the language, this answer is using Perl notation. The exact replace syntax depends on your used language.

You need to do it with two regexes. The first one that removes the punctuation and the second one to replace the whitespace with underscores.

```
s/[^\w\s]//g
```

Means match `[^\w\s]` and replace it with ''. `\w` a word character (contains different characters depending on your regex engine at least 0-9a-zA-Z_ if your language supports Unicode it can be that all letters are in `\w`)

`\s` a whitespace character

`[]` a character class

`^` at the first position inside a character class is the negation

`[^\w\s]` all characters that are not \w and \s

This will replace anything that is not a word character and not a whitespace with nothing.

The second step is to replace the remaining whitespace with _

```
s/\s/_/g
```

Your regex `(Chapter)( )([0-9])(:)( .*)` to find your row can also be improved. If you use brackets, you create capturing groups, that means the matched pattern is stored into a variable. So it makes no sense to search for `Chapter` and store this into a variable, its already known. if you don't need those variables you can reduce your regex to:

```
Chapter\s*\d:.*
```

`\d` is the same than `[0-9]`

`\s*` means any amount of whitespace

Do you expect chapter numbers bigger than 9? Then use

```
Chapter\s*\d+:.*
```

`+` means at least one, so `\d+` will match on at least one digit.

Comment: Not Perl. Regular text editor's find and replace with regular expression feature. i.e. OpenOffice, TextWrangler, Eclipse, LibreOffice.

Comment: Than try to use the part between the first two slashes in the find field, and the part between slash 2 and 3 in the replace field. But it can be that it will not work in every editor, depends on the used regex engine.

Comment: Is there any alternative replacement procedures without perl notation? If not, how can I put those two in a perl script? I'm talking about putting both find and replace portions in a perl script. I will be using TextWrangler for mac.

Comment: @user730009 Perl syntax is only the complete match replace command. The pattern itself is pretty universal (see my last comment). If this is not working you should check the TextWrangler help on what kind of regular expression it does support.

Comment: The problem is that these text "Chapter 1: My name is: Shojib (aka mhs)" are mixed with other text. So I have to find it first and then replace the spaces and colons in it using grep or regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement is not terribly clear, but this should do it...

`/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g`

Put any character you do *not* want to replace with an underscore in the brackets

Comment: Not Perl. Regular text editor's find and replace with regular expression feature.